# Meaning of ForkLift Name and BaseURL options and their equivalent in WinSCP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp, winscp

What is the meaning of *Name* and *Base URL* options of ForkList.

See the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtplr6LYXLs - 3:21 - 5:00?

[image]

And where are they set in WinSCP?

Answer (score 0):

The *Name* is a name you give to the session. It can be anything.

The *Base URL* is probably used, when you want to open the file in your web browser. In WinSCP that's equivalent to *"URL root path"* (empty in this case) and *"Web server hostname override"* (as the IP is same, it can be left empty too) in [Generate HTTP URL Extension options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url#options).

---

What really matters is the *"Server"* only. In WinSCP that's equivalent to *"Host name"*.

Comment: The path to the site on the main machine - `C:/OSPanel/domains/localhost/mysite` . The path to the site on the virtual machine is `192.168.0.18/home/bitrix/www/mysite` . @MartinPrikryl Based on these values, the question arises - what values do I need to specify in the window elements https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url#options

Comment: The local path is not relevant to this at all. The HTTP URL of your webserver is relevant.

Comment: I understand that. But what is the HTTP URL of your website?

Comment: What is the HTTP URL and how can I find it? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: What is the HTTP URL and how can I find it? @MartinPrikryl In the video in Remote Path, the path of the `www` is indicated (`/home/bitrix/www`) on the Linux virtual machine. Local Path sets the path on the Windows machine - `/Users/las/Desktop/site`.

Comment: If you do not know what is HTTP URL, why do you even try to use the HTTP URL Extension? Do you understand what is it for?

Comment: I want to use a virtual machine with bitrix, whose pages are displayed at 192.168.0.18 (see video). To do this, you need to set the values of the input elements of the window given in the question.@MartinPrikryl

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. This all looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). – For now do not put anything to those fields. I believe you do not need it for anything. And even if you do, so far it looks like the empty values are correct for your setup.

Comment: I do not understand what is the HTTP URL and what is the HTTP URL Extension. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: So why are you trying to set it up?  It's not necessary to manage your site.

Comment: I do not know what do you mean by *"associate"*. – Just browse to the right local folder in local (left) panel of WinSCP?

Comment: I need to match the folder on the Windows machine and on the server in order to transfer data from the home system to the server

Comment: And the problem is? – So browse the the respective folder in WinSCP panels and do transfer the files as you need.

Comment: Is it clear now or do you need more help?